# CSS Media Query Load Order

Tags: css, image, media, resolution, retina

I'd like to know what happens when I lay my code structure as shown below. Does an iPad user load "**stripes.png**" and *then* "**stripes-X2.png**" this way?

```
div.stripes {

    background: url("stripes.png");
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 

    div.stripes {

        background: url("stripes-X2.png");
    }

}
```

If that's the case, would this be a better alternative to make sure each device only loads appropriate version of the image for itself?

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), (max-resolution: 191dpi) { 

    div.stripes {

        background: url("stripes.png");
    }

}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 

    div.stripes {

        background: url("stripes-X2.png");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes in the first code both images are loaded. In the second only are loaded the images if it fits with the media query, but it's not bulletproof for all resolutions/browsers/devices

Comment: So, can't I make sure that every browser will at least load one of the images? If I can, I'll use this structure on my site.

Comment: With first code, all browsers load the `stripes.png` image and only if mediaquery fits load `stripes-X2.png`. But in the second code, only devices that fits with these mediaqueries will be load or one image or the other. I think it's better the first code.